# Como posso utilizar um formulário Website através do Android?

Tags: android

Sou novo em programação Android(java) e já faz um tempo que estou com um problema: preciso utilizar um formulário da Web no Android, transferindo dados entre EditText e input, Button e Button etc.. mas sem Webview.

Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer isso.

Comment: Porque o Webview não funciona pra você? Ele seria a solução ideal já que permitiria exibir e gerenciar um conteúdo html renderizado dinamicamente.

Comment: algo assim http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

Comment: Gostaria de utilizar um formulario em uma activity normal com um botão que realizasse as mesmas funções de um formulario em um site, como se fosse uma máscara, acho que precisa converter a pagina em html e depois realizar as funções. O webview ficaria muito vulnerável e mostraria as propagandas da página.

Answer (score 2):

Através desse tópico acho que vai te ajudar nisso

link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505157/how-to-send-the-data-from-edittext-to-a-website

```
public void postData(String email, String password) {
// Cria um novo HttpClient e um Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.seusite.com/registrar.php");

try {

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", email));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


    // Executa a requesição HTTP Post 
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

} catch (IOException e) {

   }
}
```

Comment: Acho que não é bem isso que ele quer! Ou talvez eu tenha entendido errado!

Comment: Então pelo que eu entendi ele quer enviar os dados do EditText no app, para um formulário no site dele.

Comment: Isso mesmo @ReynaldoTadeu, preciso fazer isso e pegar um valor na próxima página.